# More options beyond dbFront

Tags: database

https://dbfront.com/ is a standalone tool that focuses on managing the "data" of a database.

Requirements

- As a Software Vendor Administrator, I need to make changes to data in a way that is not yet possible in the software application.
- (For example, someone adds in "BonusField" in the database, but haven't made any changes to the custom software frontend, but would show in the separate software that I'm looking for)
- Technically illiterate users might function as the Vendor Admin.
- I don't need/want any RDBMS maintenance or admin tools, only "Data Management". The software I am looking for SHOULD NOT have schema editing tools.
- I have a database has a clear schema with primary keys, foreign keys, constraints, tables, and fields. DBFront proves that database metadata can be read to dynamically build a User Interface.
- For foreign keys, I don't want to have to manually type in ForeignKey IDs. There should be a User Interface element which makes this more convenient to lookup.
- I should be able to easily navigate through entities exploring data.
- SQL Querying would be a bonus, what's most important is CRUD - Listing, Editing Details, inserting new records, and deleting.
- It should look modern, not dated.
- Ideally, it should support postgreSQL, but that's not essential. I'm happy to start new projects with another RDBMS if an option is compelling enough. (So far this is only DbFront)
- It SHOULD NOT be software for generating code to deploy, it SHOULD be software that is configured by the database metadata during runtime. Minimal user configuration is tolerable.
- It MAY use a Grid to show rows, and allow direct editing
- It MAY show "Details" view of a record for editing
- It MAY be a web application that can be hosted alongside the primary custom developed software.
- Ideally it was have extensible support for File uploads. This might mean storing in a blob column in the database, but it would ideally save to a separate web-api endpoint which returns a reference (ID or URL) to store in a database field.

It's very difficult to Google Search for solutions to this. Usually the results are dominated by RDBMS management tools (such as pgAdmin).

Comment: Postgrest is an interesting tool for building an API directly from a database, but doesn't include a GUI.

Comment: https://xlinesoft.com/phprunner/ - might be close, but it's quite dated in how it looks, and I have never used it (I'm not sure if it meets my criteria)

Comment: As the developer behind dbFront, is there a specific reason you are looking for another option?

Comment: @AnthonyVO See OP for list of "Requirements". From memory, dbFront doesn't meet most of my needs.

Comment: Of the requirements listed, the only fully missing item is Grid editing.   PostGreSQL was listed as optional,  and File Uploads are supported using the DB's Blob or VarBinary fields.

Comment: @AnthonyVO How about 1) Clicking a FK value to take you to the related entities details view? 2) "It should look modern, not dated." is dbfront skinnable at all? ;and 3) How about blog storage? Can they be stored in a folder or S3 or somewhere else?  - DbFront is great, but I am also looking for other options for contrast.

Comment: 1) Yes to Following a FK value, 2) Yes to theming [https://dbfront.com/themes], 3) Yes to BLOBs in database, No to filesystem.   If you find any missing features please request or vote for them via [https://dbFront.com/suggestions].

Comment: @AnthonyVO 2) I would call that changing the colour scheme. For me "theme" would allow full UI reskinning.

Comment: The Theming in dbFront is definitely more then just changing the color.  All the best in your search.

Comment: As of 2020, dbFront supports Grid editing.  [https://dbfront.com/qa/214/done-grid-editing]